# C++ What exactly is the element type in an uninitialized local (not global)int array?

Tags: c++

I'm reviewing for my C++ exam and I found that in one of my tutorial solution it says

```
string sa[10]; //all elements are empty strings
int ia[10]; //all elements are 0
int main()
{
  string sa2[10]; //all elements are empty strings
  int ia2[10]; //all elements are undefined
}
```

But when I ran it on my computer with

```
cout<<typeid(ia2[i])name()<<endl;
```

the type here is all ints which is not an undefined element? 
So I'm curious whether or not the solution is wrong or is there any subtle reason for me not printing a right type?
Any help is appreciated, thank you!

**Added**
this is what I found from the tutorial solution:
– If the int array was defined inside a function, then the value of each
element is undefined.
– If the int array was defined outside any function, then the value of
each element is 0.

Comment: They *type* is of course `int`, as type is static in C++. But what are the **values**?

Comment: @scohe001 hello, in the tutorial it doesn't initialize the array so i don't think that's the point of this problem

Comment: Fundamental types are not initialized, class types are initialized with default constructor. Typeid has nothing to do with values. So the comments in your code are incorrect.

Comment: The use of the word _"undefined"_ is perhaps misleading (and smells a bit like JavaScript). It would be better to say that the elements in the local `ia2` are *uninitialized*, which is to say their type is well known but their value is not.

Comment: @Quimby Why do you think the comments are incorrect?

Comment: @ZihanChen the answer to my question is that the value of the `int`'s in the array is undefined. It's whatever the compiler feels like. **That** is what your tutorial means when it says "the elements are undefined"

Comment: `typeid` don't read the values, only the type, which is still int. Like @scohe001 said

Comment: The tutorial is poorly worded.    All elements of an array of `int` are, by definition, of type `int`. The type of something specifies (among other things) the set of possible values it can hold.   All elements of `ia2` are of type `int`, so each can represent values in some range, but they only hold one value at a time. The comment "all elements are undefined" is incorrect, since `int ia2[10]` defines `ia2` as an array of ten `int`.  However, the elements are all *uninitilalised* so their values are *indeterminate*, and accessing the value of any element gives *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: "Undefined value" means that you can have any random value that is in type range inside your variable. For ex. ia2[5] may have value 123456789. It's because memory is not cleaned after previous use of it (for performance reasons). In many cases you may asume that your variable is initialized by 0 as on 9 out of 10 application runs you will see 0 as a value of it, but this may lead to an error at runtime as initial value will be really a random number and not zeroed one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is some kind of shortcut in comment that may be misleading; one may read:

```
string sa[10]; //all elements are empty strings
int ia[10]; //all elements are int initialized to 0
int main()
{
  string sa2[10]; //all elements are empty strings
  int ia2[10]; //all elements are int with undefined values
}
```